# Set Iframe Source on Remote Page via URL Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, parameter-passing

I have 3 pages that I am working with.

**shop_mobile.php**

This page retrieves product data from MySQL db and lists formats it.  It accepts the url parameters brand=BRANDNAME and cat=CATEGORY.

Here are two examples of this page in action:
http://solanocycle.com/shop_mobile.php?brand=KYMCO&cat=KYMCO%20Scooters

http://solanocycle.com/shop_mobile.php?brand=peacesports&cat=Peace%20Sports%20Scooter

**vehicles.html**

This page contains links to view specific product listings pages (i.e.  "KYMCO Scooters", "Peace Sports Scooters").  When these links are clicked, they should all take the user to the same page (view.html) but pass URL parameters which tell the Iframe within view.html which url to use as its source.

**view.html**

This page contains an Iframe which gets its source from the URL parameters passed by the links from vehicles.html

*Note:*

I tried using the solution provided at [How do I pass URL parameter to an iFrame in Wordpress page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790867/how-do-i-pass-url-parameter-to-an-iframe-in-wordpress-page) to solve my problem, but I have never used jquery before and I was not able to get it working correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***More Info***

Sample of a link from Vehicles.html

`<a href="view.html?http://solanocycle.com/shop_mobile.php?brand=KYMCO&cat=KYMCO%20Scooters">KYMCO Scooters</a>`

What I think View.html should do:

1. Extract "http://solanocycle.com/shop_mobile.php?brand=KYMCO&cat=KYMCO%20Scooters" from the url "view.html?http://solanocycle.com/shop_mobile.php?brand=KYMCO&cat=KYMCO%20Scooters" and store it as a variable called $embedLink.
2. Display an Iframe with $embedLink as its source url.

Comment: Do you have sample code?

Comment: Am I to assume that your problem is extracting the URL params on view.html and having the iframe reflect them?

Comment: A updated my question with a little more information and some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your link(s) on vehicles.html are well structured, as follows:

view.html?url=http://solanocycle.com/shop_mobile.php?brand=KYMCO&cat=KYMCO%20Scooters

The necessary jQuery for view.html would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var regex = /\?url=(.*)/,
    $embedLink = document.location.href.match(regex)[1];
    $('iframe').attr('src', $embedLink);
});
</script>
```

Obviously you would replace 'iframe' with an id or class of the iframe to be more specific.

The alternate would be to use php to extract the request parameter and echo it out in place of the iframe's src attribute:

```
<?php $embedLink = (isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : ''); ?>

<iframe src="<?php echo $embedLink; ?>"></iframe>
```

I would recommend performing sanitisation of the request parameter in both cases in order to prevent XSS.